# Visual Studio 2015 Community Sign In error

Tags: visual-studio

I have a copy of VS 2015 community at home and can sign in fine, but at work I cannot. When I click check for updated licenses and enter my email address I get a script error

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNG0G.png)

I click continue numerous times and I select my account and the error reappears, I click continue and I get this screen

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W40zZ.png)

Any Ideas? I am on an intranet at work.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking on Sign-In get the below screen.

[VS 2015 signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60nWF.jpg)

I was able to fix the issue with VS 2015 update 3

Visual Studio IDE

Subscriptions and product keys

We've addressed feedback in Update 3 from customers using subscriptions through an online identity or product keys to unlock the IDE, in the following ways:

You are no longer required to visit http://my.visualstudio.com to activate your assigned Visual Studio Cloud subscription, and can immediately start using the Visual Studio IDE as soon as the subscription is assigned.
We've improved error handling when applying a product key.
All user account and licensing operations are now secured by using HTTPS.
We've made accessibility improvements in the Account Settings dialog for activating a subscription and entering a product key.
New Re-authentication every ~8 days is no longer required to keep the personalization account active and synchronizing roaming settings.